# On the command line, how do you find out where apps are installed?

Tags: package-management

I am running red hat linux and wanted to know where are my apps installed? Right now I have vim 7.2 and I want to know where that is installed so I can update it to 7.4. How does one find out where apps are installed? What is the equivalent of program files folder for linux?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is your distribution. And "program files" in linux is usually /usr. But it can be app is installed in /opt. or /usr/local/bin

Comment: You don't need to know where it's installed in order to upgrade it.  Just install the updated package provided by RH.  If RH hasn't released an updated package yet, then wait until they do.  If you're feeling confident and brave, see if Centos or Fedora has and download the source rpm from them and rebuild it on your RH system, then install the resulting package.  I recommend ignoring any advice telling you how to download and compile the original source - you clearly do not know enough about RH to safely upgrade a program like vim from unpackaged source - the risk is an unfixable broken mess.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1: use the `which` command to find the location of the binary. This may return a symlink, so be careful in what use you make of it.

Answer 2: use `rpm` to find out what packages are installed and to find out the payload of those packages. For example, `rpm -qa | grep vim` will tell you what packages are installed that have the string "vim" in the package name. Then, `rpm -ql <packagename>` will list all files that were installed when the package with that name was installed.

Note that those examples (in answer 2)are for Red Hat-based distributions, and will not work in Debian-based distributions.

Also, if you're trying to upgrade a program that was installed with a package manager to one that isn't using a package manager, I strongly suggest you not do so. It will create more problems for you own the road than it will solve.

Comment: John, which command search only in PATH! And rpm will work only in rpm-based distributions

Comment: If the OP executes programs that are not in his `$PATH` ha probably knows where they are, and wouldn't have asked, so that `which` only searchs in `$PATH` really isn't relevant. And the answer already says that the `rpm` commands are for RedHat-based distributions so that's not a relevant point either.

Comment: @Henrik, if program run via script (located in PATH) or via alias then OP will not know where is the command and which will not help

Comment: @RomeoNinov if a common program such as `vim` is being invoked by a script, then the OP has modified his/her system to do so, and will know what modifications he/she has made, so again, that object is irrelevant.